# Intellij does not show autocompletion for groovy methods

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

So, i have intllij 2016.1.3 (professional)
I imported an existing grails 2.5 project, created a grails 2.5 library by pointing to grails installation. Every thing seem to work, other then the suggestions for groovy methods (eg default groovy methods collect, find, sort, eachWithIndex etc). Intellij does not show suggestions for this groovy methods, and does not even recognize it, even if i manually write the method name. Surprizingly it shows suggestions for collectParallel, eachParallel.

Tried setting up a groovy library, used groovy-eclipse compiler, but not luck.
What could be going wrong?

Comment: Since you pay for support, why not file a ticket with them? if it's not a bug introduced with the new version, then the usual IDE raindance may work: rebuild the project, restart the ide, change your BuildConfig.groovy back-and-forth and reimport the "changes' ...

Comment: May be you want to show an example? By the way, did try running the code to see if that works or not?

Comment: Code works perfect

Comment: just filed a support request, lets see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to remove dslActivationStatus.xml from `~/Library/Preferences/<IntellijVersion>/options/` (OSX El capitan)

This was suggested by intellij support team after investigating it for few days.

Comment: Again, saved me time. After an update the file came back... and I forgot what fixed it :)

luckily I favorited this answer.  Thanks @sudhir

Comment: I don't see anything like that file on a Linux version 2018 Ultimate

Comment: @JesseBoyd `~/.<IntellijVersion>/config/options` on Linux